# NSDateFormatter returning wrong Date String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am converting NSDate to string using following code:

```
+(NSString*) stringFromDate:(NSDate*) date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];


    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

It is working fine but when i use following code it returns 1 day less

```
NSString *dateString = [HJDateFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

What is wrong with this code????

Comment: What is timezone of your picker.date?

Comment: I have set the timezone to new york USA on iPhone

Comment: Try this, in stringFromDate method instead of GMT write your UTC timezone.

Comment: Set your UIDatePicker's timeZone property to the same zone as in your NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

try This code

```
+(NSString*) stringFromDate:(NSDate*) date
{

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

   NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
   [dateFormatter setLocale:posix];
   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem By Aleksey Kozhevnikov answer that is:

"Set your UIDatePicker's timeZone property to the same zone as in your NSDateFormatter"